# Java Visualization Library for Creating Graphs with detailed nodes and varying-width edges

Tags: java, graph, visualization

I am looking for a library with which I can visualize arrangement of components of a system. The output would have following requirements:

1. The Nodes of the graph should be able to contain some sub-nodes.
2. As the graph is weighted, I would like if I can specify the width of the edges or separate them using colours(if width is not possible).

The following a rough sketch of what I want.

[image]

I have looked at a couple of posts and other google results to find certain libraries like JUNG, GraphStream. But, as I have a deadline I cannot explore each of the libraries.

Guys, can you please suggest me a library (Java-preferred) to do this kind of visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) might be good for this task. It's a simple text-based language for describing graph visualizations, including attributes such as edge width. Since it's text-based, it's easy to generate in any language, including Java (I've once generated a pretty complex graph from a bash script). There are libraries which make it possible to display graphs in GrahpViz format, for example [idot](http://code.google.com/p/idot/). Also, check out the [Resources page](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php) on GraphViz site, they list some additional Java resources which might be useful.

Comment: Can you give me an example to create a nested box for the example shown in the question? Thanks

Comment: I haven't done this in practice, but have a look at [this discussion](http://old.nabble.com/nesting-clusters-td30080702.html). The second post from top has a PDF attachment which looks similar to what you are looking for.